# String Changes When Put Into a Model [Swift]

Tags: arrays, swift, string, model

I'm running a loop to get a list of strings and write them into the model.

Here's the model:

```
class URLListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var urlArray = [URLStringList]()
    
}

class URLStringList: Identifiable {
    var urlString: String

    init(urlString: String) {
        self.urlString = urlString
    }
}
```

Here's the function that contains a loop:

```
    func getBonusURLsArray(myRange: Array<String>) {
        
        let storage = Storage.storage().reference()
        
        for dateX in myRange {

            self.bonusUrlString = "" // reset url

            storage.child("monthlyBonus/monthly_bonus_\(dateX).jpeg").downloadURL{ (bonusUrl, err) in

                if err != nil{
                    print ((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                    print("there's an error")
                    return
                }

                self.bonusUrlString = "\(bonusUrl!)"
                print("Here's the url: \(self.bonusUrlString)")
                
                let newURLString = URLStringList(urlString: self.bonusUrlString)
                print("What to write: \(newURLString)")
                urlCheck.urlArray.append(newURLString)                
            }
        }
        return
    }
```

`urlCheck` is declared as follows: `@EnvironmentObject var urlCheck: URLListViewModel`
`bonusUrlString` is declared as follows: `@State var bonusUrlString = ""`

The line `print("Here's the url: \(self.bonusUrlString)")` returns the url as a string, which is what I need.

But the line `print("What to write: \(newURLString)")` returns some weird string, e.g. "CustomLoginDemo.URLStringList: 0x60000007e6a0".

1. What is this weird string?
2. I want to insert `self.bonusUrlString` into the array `URLStringList()` of the model. How do I do that so that the line `print("What to write: \(newURLString)")` returns the url as a string?

Comment: It seems you didn´t save the url string but your custom `URLList`. The string you are seeing is when you print a customobject in the console or use the object inside a string interpolation. But this would need a [mre] to be solved.

Comment: You are confusing yourself with your bad naming of variables.
`self.bonusUrl` is of type `String`, so when you print it you get a string that you can easily read.
Although you call it a Url it is not a URL, it is a String, a better name would be `self.bonusUrlString`.

`let newURL = URLList(url: self.bonusUrl)` is of type `URLList`, whatever you declare this as (probably an array of Strings), 
and when you print it, the print uses the `URLList.description` or similar to give you an idea 
of what this is. Again, a better name would be `newUrlStringList`.